# How to connect oracle database remotely from a ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, nhibernate

> I have two PC. In one pc(PC1) i have
>   installed oracle express edition 10g
>   (10.2.0.0 as far as i know). And in
>   another(PC2) i have installed visual
>   studio 2008 sp1. In PC2 the ASP.Net
>   application is running. But i can not
>   connect to the oracle database to PC1.
>   PC1 and PC2 are connected by
>   LAN(TCP/IP {Actually they are
>   connected by wire and given two IP} )
>   But it was working perfectly while
>   both ASP.net application and database
>   were in the samae PC. can any one help?

the NHibernate configuration file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=xe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hr;Password=hr;Unicode=True</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <!-- mapping files -->
    <mapping assembly="DataTransfer" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: this is probably a networking issue and does not belong on this forum.  Can you browse via network from one computer to the other?

Comment: Try to ping from one machine to the other. If you cannot, you have a network related problem and that needs to be solved first. If you can ping successfully, then make sure your connection string is correct.

Comment: Don't you need a 'Server' specification somewhere? I assume its trying to use the local data source 'xe' here.

Comment: I can browse another pc. I have tried "DataSource=PC1\xe" but it does not work. I have not found any solution yet. So i posted in this forum.

Comment: Is there any other forum that can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is to install the Oracle client (or thin client), configure it, and try connecting to your remote database via SQLPlus.  This takes lots of pieces out of the picture and makes sure you have basic connectivity to your database with the Oracle driver.